# MySQL - LEFT JOIN get parent from the same table

Tags: mysql

i have a table "**table1**" with an "**parents_list**" inside. Now i will get only *one parent* with the highest status for each row and from this parent the next parent (2 ups).
The query i wrote is this one. But it returns for "parent_name & parent_name_2" only **NULL**:

```
SELECT t1.id, parents.name as parent_name, parents2.name as parent_name_2
from table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table1 as parents ON parents.id = (
  SELECT id from table1 WHERE parents_list IN (SUBSTR(REPLACE(t1.parents_list,';', ','),1 , CHAR_LENGTH(t1.parents_list) - 1)) AND status > 1 ORDER BY status DESC LIMIT 1
)
LEFT JOIN table1 as parents2 ON parents2.id = (
  SELECT id from table1 WHERE parents_list IN (SUBSTR(REPLACE(parents2.parents_list,';', ','),2 , CHAR_LENGTH(parents2.parents_list) - 2)) AND status > 1 ORDER BY status DESC LIMIT 1
)
WHERE t1.date BETWEEN '2018-05-15' AND '2018-06-20'
```

The table:

```
| id | name | date | parents_list | status | 
| ---: | --- | --- | --- | ---: | 
| 1 | test 1 | 2018-05-18 |  | 3 | 
| 2 | test 2 | 2018-05-25 | ;1; | 3 | 
| 3 | test 3 | 2018-05-23 | ;5;1;4; | 8 | 
| 4 | test 4 | 2018-05-30 | ;1;3; | 5 | 
| 5 | test 5 | 2018-06-05 | ;2;4;3; | 6 |
```

The result of row "ID: 5" should be:

```
| id | parent_name| parent_name_2 |
| 5 | test 3 | test 1 |
```

but the current result is:

```
| id | parent_name| parent_name_2 |
| 5 | NULL | NULL |
```

How could i bring this query to work or is there a better way to do this?

**P.S. i can't change the table design :(**

Comment: storing parents_list as semicolon separated is bad practice. you should normalize your data

Comment: Yeah, honestly, it would be easier for you to fix your table design versus one of us doing SQL olympics to try to give you a query.

Comment: Yes i know but i cant fix it. This table is in use, sadly....
I wish i could change the design .....